# Machine Learning: Image Classification: CNN: How to identify Just Red Cars?

Tags: image, machine-learning, classification, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to come up with a way to classify if the given image contains a Red Car.

The possible outcomes of the classifier should be:

1. Image contains a CAR and it is RED. (Desired case)
2. All others where Image contains a CAR but it is NOT RED or image does not contain any Cars at all.

I know how to implement a Convolutionary NN that can classify if an image contains a CAR or not.

But I am having trouble on how to implement a fine grained image classification for this where the classifier should only identify Red Cars and ignore all other images that may contain Cars or no cars in the image.

I read the following papers but since my use case is much limited than finding similarities as proposed in the papers I am trying to see if there is a simple approach to implement this.

[Fast Training of Triplet-based Deep Binary Embedding Networks](http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2016/papers/Zhuang_Fast_Training_of_CVPR_2016_paper.pdf)

[Learning Fine-grained Image Similarity with Deep Ranking](http://users.eecs.northwestern.edu/~jwa368/pdfs/deep_ranking.pdf)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just treat it as a classification problem with two classes: "Red car" - "No red car". Label every instance of your training data this way. There is no need to train a "car" classifier first.

> I know how to implement a Convolutionary NN that can classify if an image contains a CAR or not.

Good. Then this should be done within seconds (+ time for labeling).

> I read the following papers but since my use case is much limited than finding similarities as proposed in the papers I am trying to see if there is a simple approach to implement this.
>
> Fast Training of Triplet-based Deep Binary Embedding Networks
>
> Learning Fine-grained Image Similarity with Deep Ranking

Yes, simply treating it as a classification problem as described above. If you need a starter, have a look at the [Tensorflow Cifar10 tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn/).

Comment: Thanks Martin. What I am wondering is how many images will I need because the number of possible images that will not contain a RED CAR will be huge compare to the number of images that DO contain a RED CAR. If I train 10k RED CAR Images and 30k non RED CAR images, containing cars of all colors and images that contain NO CARS, will it be enough to get good accuracy? Of course I do plan on running the test to figure this out myself, but, any thought would be great on the number of training images. Thanks.

Comment: It is impossible to say this in advance without more information. I __guess__, if you have 224px x 224px images which contain only the car (if a car is there) and if your data contains other red objects, 100 images per class could be enough when you use a very simple topology to get >90% accuracy.

Comment: Asking this question is a little bit like asking somebody how the weather in Buxtehude will we tomorrow: Impossible to tell without a weather service, fairly easy if you have one.